# R: write.xlsx2 file name as Sys.time()

Tags: r

I am trying to output my data frame in R to Excel file with write.xlsx2 function.

I would like to set the file name as today's data though.

I tried codes below:

```
paste(c(format(Sys.time(), "%m%d%Y"), '.xlsx'), sep="")
```

And the result was

```
[1] "03202017" ".xlsx"
```

Okay. I gotta get rid of that quotation marks.

```
noquote(paste0(c(format(Sys.time(), "%m%d%Y"),'.xlsx'), sep =""))
```

It seems to work but the result has that annoying space in between as below:

```
[1] 03202017 .xlsx
```

The worst part was it DOES NOT work in write.xlsx2 function:

```
write.xlsx2(fcst,noquote(paste0(c(format(Sys.time(), "%m%d%Y"),'.xlsx'), sep ="")) , sheetName = "Sheet1", append=F)
```

Error Message as below:

```
Error in createWorkbook(type = ext) : 
  Unknown format 03202017Unknown format xlsx
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (type == "xls") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (type == "xlsx") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

What have I done wrong? How can I remove the space in between.

How can I output an excel file with today's date in file name?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried: paste0(format(Sys.time(), "%m%d%Y"),'.xlsx')

Comment: It worked... Don't know why my brain always misses the simplest thing. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code I've used for this kind of thing before, using the `stringr` package:

```
require(stringr)
todaysdate <- paste(str_match(Sys.Date(), "..(..)-(..)-(..)")[,c(3,4,2)], collapse=".")
```

Of course, you can change the `collapse` argument to match what you want to separate the date numbers with, including `""` for no separation.